# This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect. No Django procress running

Tags: python, django, localhost, django-manage.py

I have the weirdest bug ever: yesterday in the morning I was using my program without any issues (web application made with Django + react/redux & javascript). After some bugs I decide to take again from scratch so I clone the git then I am trying to relaunch my app and I have this:

[image]

However I have no issues when I launch my app :

Backend : 
[image]

Frontend : 
[image]

And the weird thing is I can't see any process running on port 8000 of my computer: 
[image]

And the code which is on git was working perfectly like 2 days ago so if someone got an idea I would like to hear it.

EDIT 0: 
I've tried to run `sudo python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` and access it through my external IP adress 
I've also tried to run it on differents ports

EDIT 1: I've reinstalled linux from scratch and still nothing.

Comment: did you try `runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`?

Comment: That-s really weird, anyway as you have found that nothing is listening on port 8000 it is likely that the problem is in the local python process that does not start correctly, and you said you have just recreated the dir tree for first I would check file permissions.

Comment: BearBrown yes it didn't work either. @Marco Do you have an idea of which files ?

Comment: @Marco i've ran `sudo chmod 777 -R /myProjectFolder` and it's still not working

Comment: Can you raise the errorlevel and maybe get some more debug messages ? you should have this flag ./manage.py runserver --verbosity X

Comment: it gives the same output for x=0,1,2,3

Comment: `curl -i http://127.0.0.1:8000`?

Comment: Side note: Do **not** run your server as root. You don't need to run it as root to bind to port 8000, and by running as root, if your server was comprimised by a remote attacker, you have now given them the keys to the kingdom, as they can do anything they could ever want to your machine as root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found myself what the problem is, it comes from a conflict between django and the library aiocoap. Indeed I am working with library to make http request to a server which runs on a different computer to get datas in real time sent by some raspberry pi (big JSON you can see in the first image of my post). I am now talking with the creator of this library because i did not modified this part of my program since a long time and it was working great before.